# Optional stroke on Flutter charts bar chart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-charts

I have a `charts.BarChart` in which I want to highlight one of the bars in the chart by adding a border to the bar.

This is possible to do by following [this example](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/bar_charts/grouped_fill_color): I can use `colorFn` and `fillColorFn` to color the border and the interior of the bar respectively. By default, `colorFn` does nothing at all, but by setting `BarRendererConfig.strokeWidthPx` to a positive value, `colorFn` controls the border color.

Now, to color only a single bar, my naive approach was to return `charts.MaterialPalette.black` in `colorFn` for the relevant bar, and `charts.MaterialPalette.transparent` for all other ones. This doesn't quite work since the non-highlighted bars now end up being padded with the value of `strokeWidthPx`. A better approach is to simply ensure that `colorFn` and `fillColorFn` return the same color for the non-highlighted bars. This is better but still not quite perfect: Even though the border has the same color as its interior, it's still possible to see that the border is rendered separately:

[image]

This doesn't happen for the default 0 value of `strokeWidthPx`.

So the question is: Is there a way to indicate to Flutter charts that I don't want the border to be drawn for a given bar?

Suggestions for alternative approaches to highlight a particular bar (using something that's not color) are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed there is: the `charts.Series` constructor has a `strokeWidthPxFn` paramenter, and returning `0` for the non-highlighted bars does exactly what is desired here.